# How can I dump the definition all tables to text file of particular schema in PostgreSQL

Tags: linux, postgresql, psql

I want to dump the definition of all the tables present in particular schema in one text file in PostgreSQL.

Can someone please help me with the query?!

Note -My working env is Linux and I want to execute the query from the script file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can do that using `pg_dump`

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name for your reply. Here, what should I pass the value for the parameter --table in pg_dump query if I want to get the definition of all the tables in particular schema. Can you please help me with the query.